# Specify environment vars with exec:// componant

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to execute a command using the `exec://` component that requires an environment variable to be set.

Is it possible to set an environment variable for the `exec://` execution context ?
Something like this header:

```
ExecBinding.EXEC_COMMAND_ENV_VARS
```

I have not found something like that on the component documentation.

As a workaround i can create a Bash wrapper of the command but it is not as handy as setting env vars in Camel directly.